# Problema Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Tags: python

Con este conjunto de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando correr este código para generar una predicción de eficiencia :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
myfile = drive.CreateFile({'id': '1uJ0Y_WF1OspE46fAulNJPokdZ9gbfQYl'})
myfile.GetContentFile('EstudioCaso.csv')


dataset = numpy.genfromtxt("EstudioCaso.csv", skip_header=1, dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")
print (dataset)
training_data = numpy.genfromtxt("EstudioCaso.csv", skip_header=1, usecols=(0, 1, 2, 4), dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")
training_targets = numpy.genfromtxt("EstudioCaso.csv", skip_header=1, usecols=(4), dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")




model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_data, training_targets, epochs=200, batch_size=500)
scores = model.evaluate(training_data, training_targets)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente

> Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Esto es un código que me permitirá obtener una red neuronal utilizando Keras y lo estoy corriendo en *Google Colab*. Parte de este código está disponible en [github](https://gist.github.com/spicyramen/a171ee9497f2035078030dbe6cae6bbb).

Agradezco toda la ayuda posible.

Comment: Creo que el problema deba estar en el paso de parámetros el método espera un Tensor y estás pasando un array de NumPy. Posiblemente no importaste la librería que permite hacer la conversión de tipos. Revisa la [Documentación de Modelos secuenciales de keras](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/) en tu primera línea sólo importas Secuential, quizás necesites algo más.

Comment: Estoy leyendo toda la documentacion pero hay demasiadas cosas que no entiendo. Mi nivel de programacion es muy basico pero intentare adaptar el codigo a la documentacion

Comment: El la sección de setup de Secuential indican que se deben importar unas librerías de Tensorflow que no aparecen en tu código. Es posible que ahí se encuentre el fallo. `import tensorflow as tf \\n
from tensorflow import keras \\n
from tensorflow.keras import layers` Tu arrancas importando directamente de keras.

Comment: Le agrege la importacion de esas librerias pero sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Falta algo más. Descarga e instala **[Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/es-es/pycharm/download/)** para hacer pruebas. Te va a ayudar a revisar los `__doc__` de los métodos para saber la parametrización correcta. Usa la versión free es más que suficiente.

Comment: Existe alguna posibilidad de correr alguna libreria kera en google colab que me permita utilizar las funcionalidades de Pycharm?

Comment: No lo se. **Nunca he usado** google colab. La sugerencia que hice apunta a que puedas hacer pruebas en tu equipo.

Comment: A es que en la compu no tengo permiso de administrador. Va a ser complejo poder instalarlo. De todas formas muchgas gracias por la sugerencia !!!!!!!

Comment: Ojo: En la pregunta anterior señalaste que no accesabas los datos. Es fácil X['f2'] te devuelve la tercera columna de X, Y['f0'] es la quinta columna que fue leída en Y. Quizás puedas armar el Tensor manualmente para pasarlo como parámetro. Estoy mirando la documentación. Si logro averiguar suficiente regreso para tratar de darte una mano. **Si lo resuelves postea la solución**.

Comment: Mejorar entreanmiento-test para prediccion en redes neuronales  en esta nueva pregunta cambio un poco el modelo pero necesito ayuda para calibrar el modelo